# Using induction to prove an equality in harmonic numbers

Tags: discrete-mathematics, induction, harmonic-numbers

Question: Prove that harmonic numbers satisfy the equality using induction
$$
H_{1}+ H_{2} + · · · + H_{n} = (n + 1)H_{n} − n.
$$
I have done the basis step: $(1 + 1)H_{1} − 1 = 1$. Correct.

Done the inductive hypothesis: $(k + 1)H_{k} − k$
and started solving: 
$$
(k + 2)H_{k+1} − (k+1) = (k + 1)H_{k} − k + \frac{1}{k+1}.
$$
What do I do once I get to this part?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You’ve made a mistake on the righthand side of what you’re trying to prove: if

$$H_1+H_2+\ldots+H_k=(k+1)H_k-k\;,$$

then

$$H_1+H_2+\ldots+H_k+H_{k+1}=(k+1)H_k-k+H_{k+1}\;,$$

not

$$(k+1)H_k-k+\frac1{k+1}\;.$$

Thus, you should be trying to prove that

$$(k+2)H_{k+1}-(k+1)=(k+1)H_k-k+H_{k+1}\;.$$

Approach it the same way you’d approach proving a trigonometric identity: algebraically manipulate one side into the other, or both into an identical third expression. All you really need is that $H_{k+1}=H_k+\frac1{k+1}$.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, I hadn't realized my error there. Even so, I still am unsure where to go from that point. Once you get the right side down to $$(k+1)H_k-k+H_{k} + a/(k+1)\;.$$ what do you do?

Comment: @user3362196: Proving the last displayed equality in my answer is equivalent to verifying that $$(k+2)H_{k+1}-(k+1)-\big((k+1)H_k-k+H_{k+1}\big)=0\;,$$ which is just a matter of algebraic manipulation. For instance, it may be useful to note that $(k+2)H_{k+1}=(k+2)\left(H_k+\frac1{k+1}\right)$ and multiply that out.

Comment: I must be doing something wrong... When I simplify i get it down to k - 1 = 0 which cant be right

Comment: I think the easiest way will be to take it from Brian's second equation and substitute$$H_k=H_{k+1}-\frac1{k+1}$$on the right hand side.

Comment: @user3362196: After making the suggested substitution, multiplying out on the left, and clearing parentheses you get $$(k+2)H_k+\frac{k+2}{k+1}-k-1-(k+1)H_k+k-H_k-\frac1{k+1}\;,$$ which immediately simplifies to $$\frac{k+2}{k+1}-1-\frac1{k+1}=0\;.$$